# submitting a single field credit card form

Tags: jquery, forms

I've been playing with the single field payment system from this page:https://github.com/zdfs/toscani

Not knowing my way around javascript, I'm stuck trying to figure out how to actually submit the form once completed!  As is, when completed it displays a message from the .js file: "Hooray! You've successfully filled out your credit card information."

When trying to wrap the solution in a form tag, instead of submitting, the form it will display "Please match the requested format" in a pop up warning (here is the test page: http://fundraiserhp.com/secure/test_cc.lasso ).

I've tried adding the submit button in various places but I get the same result. Here's what I have right now:

```
 <section>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="test" value="test">
        <fieldset class="credit-card-group">
            <legend>Credit Card Information</legend>
            <label for="card-number">Credit Card Number</label>
            <input placeholder="1234 5678 9012 3456" pattern="[0-9]*" type="text" class="card-number" id="card-number">
            <label for="card-number">Expiration Date</label>
            <input placeholder="MM/YY" pattern="[0-9]*" type="text" class="card-expiration" id="card-expiration">
            <label for="card-number">CVV Number</label>
            <input placeholder="CVV" pattern="[0-9]*" type="text" class="card-cvv" id="card-cvv">
            <label for="card-number">Billing Zip Code</label>
            <input placeholder="ZIP" pattern="[0-9]*" type="text" class="card-zip" id="card-zip">               
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-9"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <button type="submi<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="signup" value="Sign up">Complete Order</button></div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- !form-group -->      
    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I took a look at the source code for the test page you've provided and noticed that all the patterns for your input fields are simply "-9*", not "[0-9]*" as in your code above (which needs to be cleaned up, FYI).

Comment: I apologize for not being clearer.  When the form is completed, a message appears saying "Hooray! You've successfully filled out your credit card information."  What I want is for the form to submit to another page (as a form does) but I can't seem to get this behavior to change!  As for the form showing -9 instead of 0-9 is interesting as the code is not written that way!